# Magento Attribute

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes

I'm looking to create a new attribute set in Magento, I based it on our 'default' set and I'd like to remove some existing attributes from the new set I've created. However, when I attempt to drag and remove I get a 'no entry' symbol. Is there anything I can do to get around this? Or is there a reason I'm being blocked from removing attributes from the new set (new set has not been used to create any products)?

Comment: what are your trying to remove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot remove system attribute from your set, because these attribute are use in core magento. I.E name, description, sku, weight etc. (any attribute with the red mark on them)

.[image]

Comment: Even attributes without the red symbol are staying put, for example 'features' in your example above.

Comment: Take a look at my update... you need to drag it right there, with in the unassigned attributes list

Answer (score 2):

Some attributes can't be deleted from a set. Like SKU, Status, Name etc. These attributes have a round red symbol on them.